# BizTalk receiving from RabbitMQ

Tags: wcf, rabbitmq, biztalk

I'm new to RabbitMQ but I have now installed onto a Windows server and have a couple of demo console apps (C#) that happily write to a read from a queue.

The following code works to pull messages from a queue called "RabbitPoCQueue_2" on the local server:

```
string queueName = "RabbitPoCQueue_2";
var factory = new ConnectionFactory();
bool keepGoing = true;
factory.HostName = "127.0.0.1";
try
{
    using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
    using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
    {
        const bool durable = false;
        channel.QueueDeclare(queueName, durable, false, false, null);

        System.Console.WriteLine(" [*] Waiting for messages.");
        while (keepGoing)
        {
            var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);
            consumer.Received += (model, ea) =>
            {
                var body = ea.Body;
                var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
                System.Console.WriteLine(" [x] Received {0}", message);
            };
            channel.BasicConsume(queue: queueName,
                                 autoAck: true,
                                 consumer: consumer);

            channel.BasicGet(queue: queueName, autoAck: true);
            System.Console.WriteLine("Press Y to continue or any other key to exit");
            keepGoing = System.Console.ReadKey().Key == ConsoleKey.Y;
        }
    }
}
```

I now need to configure a BizTalk (2016 FP3 CU5) receive location to do the same. I have ensured I've stopped the console receiver and that I have messages sat on the queue for BizTalk to collect.

I followed the article https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7401.biztalk-server-and-rabbitmq.aspx

Problem is, when I start the receive location, I get no errors but nothing is received.

The config for the WCF receive location can be seen below:

[image]

and here:

[image]

and here's a pic from the RabbitMQ management console showing messages sat on the queue:

[image]

When I look in the RabbitMQ log file, I see 2 rows on starting the receive location. I see 3 rows when starting the .Net console app (using RabbitMQ API), as shown below - first 2 rows are from BizTalk, last 3 from the console app:

```
2019-08-28 16:17:45.693 [info] <0.13361.2> connection <0.13361.2> ([::1]:16807 -> [::1]:5672): user 'guest' authenticated and granted access to vhost '/' ** Start of Receive location
2019-08-28 16:19:57.958 [info] <0.13452.2> accepting AMQP connection <0.13452.2> (127.0.0.1:17173 -> 127.0.0.1:5672)
2019-08-28 16:19:58.026 [info] <0.13452.2> connection <0.13452.2> (127.0.0.1:17173 -> 127.0.0.1:5672): user 'guest' authenticated and granted access to vhost '/' ** Receive from command line
2019-08-28 18:56:26.267 [info] <0.13452.2> closing AMQP connection <0.13452.2> (127.0.0.1:17173 -> 127.0.0.1:5672, vhost: '/', user: 'guest')
2019-08-28 18:56:39.815 [info] <0.17923.2> accepting AMQP connection <0.17923.2> (127.0.0.1:41103 -> 127.0.0.1:5672)
```

Can anyone spot where I went wrong?

Comment: Does this article help at all? https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7401.biztalk-server-and-rabbitmq.aspx

Comment: I’m afraid not. That’s the same article I followed.

Comment: I suppose it's pointless to ask if you really have to use RMQ...anyway, it's been forever since I've had to deal with this but I recall that the native WCF bits only supported the default....queue? no, but something like that.  We had to modify a lot to get it to do something actually useful.  I'd say your best plan is to start stepping through the code to find what's missing.

Comment: Hi @Johns-305 yes I’m afraid we have to use RMQ - we are collecting from a 3rd party’s queue. I am able to move forward by collecting from the queue using an orchestration that calls a helper component which uses the RMQ nuget package. I’ll leave this question up though because would be nice to remove that baggage!